# K+R 2.4: bus error when assigning (Mac OS)

Tags: c, string, string-literals, sigbus

I'm currently trying to solve exercise 2.4 of the K+R book and came across an odd error I can't really reproduce elsewhere. I'm using:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Write an alternate version of `squeeze(s1, s2)' that deletes each 
character
 * in s1 that matches any character in the string s2.
 */

void squeeze(char *s1, const char *s2);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *tests[] = {"hello", "world", "these", "are", "some", "tests"};
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]); i++) {
    printf("'%s' = ", tests[i]);
    squeeze(tests[i], "aeiou");
    printf("'%s'\n", tests[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

void squeeze(char *s1, const char *s2) {
  const size_t s2len = strlen(s2);
  s1[0] = s1[0];
  unsigned int j = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    unsigned int k;
    for (k = 0; k < s2len; k++)
      if (s1[i] == s2[k]) break;
    if (k == s2len)  // we checked every character once, didn't find a bad char
      s1[j++] = s1[i];
  }
  s1[j] = '\0';
}
```

GDB says:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x0000000100000e57 in squeeze (s1=0x100000f78 "hello", s2=0x100000fa1 
"aeiou")
at exercise2-4.c:23
23    s1[0] = s1[0];
```

The error originally occurred at `s1[j++] = s1[i]`, but I inserted `s1[0] = s1[0]` to test it independent of the variables and it occurred there as well. Obviously, I'm missing something here.

I'm compiling with `clang -O0 -g -Weverything exercise2-4.c -o exercise2-4` if that's of any relevance.

Thank you very much for your time and sorry if this question's been answered before, I haven't found any question where the error occurs at such an odd place.

Comment: If you want to write K&R style C, I think you need `clang -std=c89`

Comment: You're right, thank you @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1):

You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Instead of the array of pointers to string literals

```
char *tests[] = {"hello", "world", "these", "are", "some", "tests"};
```

you should declare a two dimensional character array. For example

```
char tests[][6] = {"hello", "world", "these", "are", "some", "tests"};
```

Also you have to reserve enough space for each element of the array if you are going to append new characters to it.

Comment: Oh jesus christ, of course! Thanks.